# How can I do like this in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to make a Textbox where users can enter comma ( , ) to separate
the word. This basically called **Tags**

for better understanding, I will give an example -

**When you ask question in StackOverflow you have to enter tags**

I am talking about that tags

and if you still have doubts you can watch this image
[image: How Tags Looks Like]

Answer (score 1):

you have to use chips

Make sure that the repositories section includes Google's Maven Repository google(). For example:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
  google()
  jcenter()
}
}
```

Add the library to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
// ...
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:<version>'
// ...
}
```

then use this code in your xml code

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
android:id="@+id/chip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/text"/>
```

you can access it from java part

```
chip.setOnClickListener {
// Responds to chip click
}
chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener {
// Responds to chip's close icon click if one is present
}

chip.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chip, isChecked ->
// Responds to chip checked/unchecked
}
```

also you can use chipgroup for dynamic chips

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <!-- Chips can be declared here, or added dynamically. -->
 </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

hope my answer be useful

if you want to add new items with comma you have to use chipgroup and create textwatcher and on each change of edittext add items between commas to list and refreh the chipgroup

**updated part**

you can create text watcher like this ,, then use java.lang splite by comma

```
        yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            
            // s is your string in edittext 
            // create an arraylist 
            // use .splite by ","
            // put result in array list
            // update your chipgroup by arraylist 
            //if it was useful set answer as correct

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.asList returns a fixed-size List backed by the array. If you want a normal mutable java.util.ArrayList you need to do this:

List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(string.split(" , ")));

Or, using Guava:

List list = Lists.newArrayList(Splitter.on(" , ").split(string));

Using a Splitter gives you more flexibility in how you split the string and gives you the ability to, for example, skip empty strings in the results and trim results. It also has less weird behavior than String.split as well as not requiring you to split by regex (that's just one option).